# Sorting element of a form in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in Access like this:
[image]
When I click on "Order" button, I want to order the "client" table (shown in the bottom) order by "firstname". How I can do? Can I use macro or I must use VBA code? So far I have only used macro, I never used VBA.

Comment: Why not just set a fixed sorting on the child form: `[firstname] asc`?

Comment: Interesting. How can I do? A "WHERE condition" in a macro?

Comment: Open the form in design view and set the Sort property on the Data tab.

Comment: But I want to order using a button

Comment: I don't need a fixed sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VBA in the OnClick Event.

Click on your button while in Design View. Then go over to the properties and go into the Event tab, click in the text box for the On Click Event. Youll see a button with 3 periods appear. Click that and select the Code Builder.

It will bring up a Sub like the below. Just put that line of code in there and your done.

```
Private Sub OrderButton_Click()

DoCmd.SetOrderBy "[FieldYouWantToSortBy]" DESC, ""

End Sub
```

Comment: OK ok..I like this VBA solution..but I never tryed with VBA. Can you explain me step  by step how I can do?

Comment: it works in this way: DoCmd.SetOrderBy "c_name DESC"

Comment: thank you. however it's enough:
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "[FieldYouWantToSortBy] DESC"

Answer (score 0):

Done. I used a macro with "SetOrderBy".

Comment: Honestly i would highly would highly recommend breaking the wall down of learning VBA. Once you get deeper into Access its going to be just a lot easier to do everything including simple things like SetOrderBy and SaveRecord commands with it.

Comment: Yes, me too.. In fact I want to understand your solution. It give me error